Regular Expression extracting strings between matches
I am trying to assign the text of a PDF to columns and using a regular expression to get the values in between matches in column headers. Ultimately for CSV.
I am getting the Year data printed twice, but want a list of Year and Temperature.
Also, I am only getting the first page of years from the PDF, please advise on that if you can, too.
PDF found here:
https://www.weather.gov/media/slc/ClimateBook/Annual%20Average%20Temperature%20By%20Year.pdf
import re
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text

PDF_path = "B:\Py\PDF_to_CSV\Annual_Average_Temperature_By_Year.pdf"

text = extract_text(PDF_path)

Year, Temp = [], []

p1 = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('Year',text)]
p2 = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('Annual Average Temperature \(F\)',text)]
for el1,el2 in zip(p1,p2):
    Year.append(text[el1+len(p1):el2])
    Temp.append(text[el1+len(p2):el2])
print(Year,Temp)

Current Output:
['ar\n\nYear\n1875\n1876\n1877\n1878\n1879\n1880\n1881\n1882\n1883\n1884\n1885\n1886\n1887\n1888\n1889\n1890\n1891\n1892\n1893\n1894\n1895\n1896\n1897\n1898\n1899\n1900\n1901\n1902\n1903\n1904\n1905\n1906\n1907\n1908\n\n'] ['ear\n\nYear\n1875\n1876\n1877\n1878\n1879\n1880\n1881\n1882\n1883\n1884\n1885\n1886\n1887\n1888\n1889\n1890\n1891\n1892\n1893\n1894\n1895\n1896\n1897\n1898\n1899\n1900\n1901\n1902\n1903\n1904\n1905\n1906\n1907\n1908\n\n']

As you can see above, the output gives a similar list for both Year and Temp (appears to be printed twice, but that is the output in VScode).*

As a side-note, I have already handled this into a nice CSV format using this code:
Merging tables that span multiple pages using Camelot
However, I am trying to learn regular expressions and to simplify code.
Thank you.

Temp.append(text[el1+len(p2):el2]) should be Temp.append(text[el2+len(p2):el2])? Also, your regex pattern should be a raw string: r'Annual Average Temperature \(F\)'

Thank you, I get [''] from el2 to el2...  when I do text[el2+len(p2) : ], I get the first page of years then the rest of the document including everything... this is very helpful to think about!

I don't see the relevance of len(p1) with determining an offset in text. Apples and pears?
